# Populating a grid view is taking too much time

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, data-binding

I am trying to bind a gridview in asp.net, but it takes me too much time. I am using stored procedure, but in microsoft sql server management studio, the stores procedure takes only 2-3 second. My problem is when i load asp page. It takes 20-30 sec to populate my gridview... any idea?

UPDATE: My problem is in my stored procedure

```
SELECT  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
        ORDER BY A.[ActiuniNumar] DESC
    ) as RowNum,
            A.[Id],
            A.[Societate_Id], 
            A.[Denumire], 
            A.[NrORC], 
            A.[CUI], 
            A.[CNP], 
            A.[Adresa], 
            A.[Localitate], 
            A.[Judet], 
            A.[Tip], 
            A.[ActiuniNumar], 
            A.[ActiuniSerie], 
            A.[ActiuniNumar] * [ValoareNominala] AS [ActiuniValoare], 
            CASE
                WHEN S.[Capital] = 0 THEN 0  
                ELSE CAST(A.[ActiuniNumar] * 100 / S.ActiuniNumar AS decimal(18, 8)) 
            END AS [ActiuniProcent], 
            A.[ActiuniNevandabileNumar], 
            A.[ActiuniNevandabileSerie], 
            A.[Diverse], 
            A.[SerieCI],
            A.[Deleted], 
            A.[ModifiedBy], 
            A.[ModifiedAt]
            INTO #Results2
    FROM [dbo].[Actionar] A
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Societate] S ON A.[Societate_Id] = S.[Id]
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND ((@ActiuniNumar IS NULL AND 1 = 1) OR (@ActiuniNumar IS NOT NULL AND (@ActiuniNumar = 0 AND A.[ActiuniNumar] <= 0) OR (@ActiuniNumar != 0 AND A.[ActiuniNumar] > 0)))
    AND [Societate_Id] = @Id
    AND ((@Filter = '' AND 1 = 1) OR (@Filter != '' AND (A.[Denumire] LIKE @Filter OR A.[NrORC] LIKE @Filter OR A.[CUI] LIKE @Filter OR A.[CNP] LIKE @Filter OR A.[ActiuniNumar] LIKE @Filter OR A.[SerieCI] LIKE @Filter)))
    and A.[Deleted] = 0
    ORDER BY A.[ActiuniNumar] DESC

    SELECT * FROM #Results2 where RowNum BETWEEN(@pageIndex -1) * @pageSize + 1 AND(((@pageIndex -1) * @pageSize + 1) + @pageSize) - 1
```

It takes me 20 sec to run..

Comment: How many rows you can get from that stored procedure?

Comment: @jgasiorowski i am using costum pagination, only 10 rows on page

Comment: You should show some code I believe

Comment: @jgasiorowski code for what?

Comment: Between brower making request to server and binding data to the view there is plenty places where something can go wrong. It is imposible to say anything what causes issues in you solution. You should specify what do you use for calling SP, are you using mvc or webforms etc. Your question lacks of that informations

Comment: @jgasiorowski i am using webforms, i have a gridview with 6-7 columns. I only called sp and binding gridview...my page is loading very hard...

Answer (score 0):

sorry if it's too late. But this happened to me. And the only solution that worked was this:

```
...
    and A.[Deleted] = 0
    --ORDER BY A.[ActiuniNumar] DESC
```

Comment the **ORDER BY**. That makes it slower.